# Reduce sine wave f-curve modifier frequency?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I've got an animation of an object with an f-curve with a sine wave (Built-in function), and a Noise modifier in the graph editor.

When I exported my animation it was too fast.

I know I can increase the number of frames to reduce the speed but I don't want to do that.

Instead, I want to reduce the frequency of the sine wave from the graph editor. Is this possible?

If not, **is it possible to slow down the frequency of the graph editor as a whole (for all animations?)**

(The second option would be way more preferable actually)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that, I found the answer (not for decreasing the speed of the graph editor animations as a whole (meaning f curve modifiers which can't be edited through keyframes since I've got only 1 key frame), but for sine wave functions.

The answer is reducing the **Phase Multiplier** below 1:

[image]

Comment: No need to apologize. And thanks for coming back to answer the question. It's actually encouraged that people answer their own questions when they figure it out on their own. It helps others learn.