# need my F-Curve sine modifier coming full circuit on Nth frame

Tags: fcurves

How can I determine the exact [Phase Multiplier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214219/reduce-sine-wave-f-curve-modifier-frequency) for an sine/cosine F-Curve modifier so that my animation ends up in the exact beginning location on the last frame of my animation?   I want to be able to then have a looping video where there is no location-jerk between last frame and repeat of the video.  I have something close on the 200 frame sequence, but it is not exact.   It would be nice if I could add a Cycles with offset to the modifier stack, but no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a driver for this.

Formula:

sin(pi/100*frame)

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, the old "driver that makes no appearance in the Graph Editor as a hint" trick!